# LangChain Chroma - load data from Vector Database

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain, chromadb

I have written LangChain code using Chroma DB to vector store the data from a website url. It currently works to get the data from the URL, store it into the project folder and then use that data to respond to a user prompt. I figured out how to make that data persist/be stored after the run, but I can't figure out how to then load that data for future prompts. The goal is a user input is received, and the program using OpenAI LLM will generate a response based on the existing database files, as opposed to the program needing to create/write those database files on each run. How can this be done?

What should I do?

I tried this as this would likely be the ideal solution:

```
vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings)
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", vectorstore=vectordb)
```

But the `from_chain_type()` function doesn't take a `vectorstore` db as an input, so therefore this doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

You need to define the retriever and pass that to the chain. That will use your previously persisted DB to be used in queries.

```
vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings)

retriever = vectordb.as_retriever()

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever)
```

Comment: How do I see what the context looks like that is being passed to the QA model/ is generated from the vector db given a certain prompt.

Comment: `retriever.get_relevant_documents("my query")` should return 4 (default) documents that match your query from the storage

Comment: Is it possible to do this with Javascript version of Langchain?

Comment: @LucaFoppiano - why 4?  If i want to get a summary of the entire corpus, it should read all documents.

Comment: @Nguaial 4 is the default number of relevant document returned. You can change the value by using ```retriever = db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 10})``` for example

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to use the Chroma vector store loader as well, but my code won't load the DB from the disk. Here is what I did:

```
from langchain.embeddings.sentence_transformer import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFDirectoryLoader
import os
import json

def load_api_key(secrets_file="secrets.json"):
    with open(secrets_file) as f:
        secrets = json.load(f)
    return secrets["OPENAI_API_KEY"]

# Setup
api_key = load_api_key()
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = api_key

# load the document and split it into chunks
loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader("LINK TO FOLDER WITH PDF")
documents = loader.load()

# split it into chunks
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1500, chunk_overlap=200)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

# create the open-source embedding function
embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

# load docs into Chroma DB
db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding_function)

# query the DB
query = "MY QUERY"
docs = db.similarity_search(query)

# print results
print(docs[0].page_content)

# save to disk
db2 = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding_function, persist_directory="./chroma_db")
```

So far no problems! Then when I load the DB with this code:

```
# load from disk
db3 = Chroma(persist_directory="./chroma_db", embedding_function=embedding_function)
db3.get() 
docs = db3.similarity_search(query)
print(docs[0].page_content)
```

The `db3.get()` already shows that there is no data in `db3`. It returns:

```
{'ids': [], 'embeddings': None, 'documents': [], 'metadatas': []}
```

Any ideas why this could by?

Comment: When I use FAISS instead of Chroma as a vector store it works. Simply replace the respective codes with `db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embedding_function)`, `db2 = db.save_local("faiss_index")` and `db3 = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embedding_function)`.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34789768)

Comment: get same issue.

Comment: I didn't find the right solution but get one workaound for me: to export db2 = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding_function, persist_directory="./chroma_db") in the place you need it. (db2.similarity_search(query) )

Comment: You're not calling `db.persist()`. I'm pretty sure you also need to specify a collection name both when create the initial object, and when you load it from disk.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers I have seen are missing one crucial step to call persist the DB. As a complete solution, you need to perform following steps.

To create db first time and persist it using the below lines.

```
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(data, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory = persist_directory)
vectordb.persist()
```

The db can then be loaded using the below line.

```
vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings)
```

Comment: I think even this has become outdated right now

Answer (score 0):

just find the following works:

```py
def fetch_embeddings(collection_name):
    collection = chromadb_client.get_collection(
        name=collection_name, embedding_function=langchain_embedding_function
    )
    embeddings = collection.get(include=["embeddings"])

    print(collection.get(include=["embeddings", "documents", "metadatas"]))

    return embeddings
```

reference:
https://docs.trychroma.com/usage-guide

Answer (score 0):

Chroma provides `get_collection` at

https://docs.trychroma.com/reference/Client#get_collection

Here's an example of my code to query an existing vectorStore >

```py
def get(embedding_function):
    db = Chroma(persist_directory="./chroma_db", embedding_function=embedding_function)
    print(db.get().keys())
    print(len(db.get()["ids"]))
```

The code output with 7580 `chunks`, as example >

```bash
Using embedded DuckDB with persistence: data will be stored in: ./chroma_db
dict_keys(['ids', 'embeddings', 'documents', 'metadatas'])
7580
```

Answer (score 0):

`RetrievalQA` itself a chain. this is how we import:

```
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
```

every chain has two important components: `PromptTemplate` and `llm`. `RetrievalQA` needs to get documents and stuff these documents into its own `PromptTemplate`. That is what this argument for:

```
chain_type="stuff",
```

`RetrievalQA` has another keyword argument `retriever`. this is a communication between `RetrievalQA` chain and different vector stores. `RetrievalQA` retrieves documents from vector stores through `retriever`. Vector stores do the `similarity search` and return the documents to the `RetrievalQA`. you created

```
vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings)
```

now have `RetrievalQA` communicates with this vector store through `retriever`

```
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, 
                                 chain_type="stuff",
                                 # this will make similarity search in vectordb
                                 retriever=vectordb_as_retriever)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def load_api_key(secrets_file="secrets.json"):
    with open(secrets_file) as f:
        secrets = json.load(f)
    return secrets["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
```

Instead of doing this you can create a `.env` (secret file) and place your openaikey. Like this:

```
OPENAI_API_KEY = "<your_key>"
```

Then load it in your main file and in your main function like this:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

USAGE:

```
load_dotenv()
```